# Group deeply nested values by property keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, lodash

I have the following structure in the app I'm working on:

```
collection {

   user_entry_1 {
      page_1_id {
         input_1_id: someValue
         input_2_id: anotherValue
      },
      page_2_id {
         ...
      }
   },
   user_entry_2 {
      ...
```

As you can see, the actual **needed** values are nested pretty deep. Now I've been fighting for hours on end with how I could group the data, so that the resulting object would look like the following:

```
collection {

  page_1_id {
    input_1_id: [value1, value2, value3...],
    input_2_id: [value1, value2, value3...]
  },
  page_2_id {
    input_3_id: [value1, value2, value3...],
    ...
```

If it's any help, I'm dealing with dynamic forms spread over multiple pages. I've tried lodash, writing custom spaghetti-functions using a ton of arrays, etc. but can't simply come up with a clever way to arrange the data like shown above. Basically I need to get the "deepest" nested values into arrays, and the key of each array would be the key of the "input" (multiple same keys, because multiple users).

I've only been coding for a couple years now, so these kinds of array/object manipulations aren't plain vanilla to me. Sorry if it's hard to read or I was unclear.

Here is my attempt:

```js
const collection = {
       user_entry_1: {
          page_1_id: {
             input_1_id: 'someValue',
             input_2_id: 'anotherValue'
          },
          page_2_id: {
             input_3_id: 'someValue' //,
             //, enter other data here:
          }
       },
       user_entry_2: {
          page_1_id: {
             input_1_id: 'someValue',
             input_2_id: 'anotherValue'
          },
          page_2_id: {
             input_3_id: 'someValue' //,
             //, enter other data here:
          }
      }
};      

//ENTER THE CODE YOU TRIED HERE:
```

As you can see my output is this:

```js
//Enter output from your attempt:
```

But I expect:

```js
//Enter desired output:
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Could you please also post your attempts? So we can see what's wrong and try to correct them

Comment: Where do value1, value2, value3 come from? You likely need to give more data in your input and make sure that maps over to the expected output you post. As stated above, add a snippet to your question and inside it, including your attempt, with the input and then we can compare your output to your expected output. I will edit your answer with a template for you to fill out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` function.

```js
var collection = { 'user_entry_1': { 'page_1_id': { 'input_1_id': 'someValue 1', 'input_2_id': 'anotherValue' }, 'page_2_id' : { 'input_1_id': 'someValue 2', 'input_2_id': 'anotherValue' }}, 'user_entry_2': { 'page_1_id': { 'input_1_id': 'someValue 2', 'input_2_id': 'anotherValue 2' }, 'page_2_id' : { 'input_1_id': 'someValue 2', 'input_2_id': 'anotherValue 2' }}};

var result = Object.entries(collection).reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{ 
  for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(value)){
     acc[k] = acc[k] || {};
     Object.entries(v).forEach(([inputKey, inputValue])=>{
       acc[k][inputKey] =acc[k][inputKey] || [];
       acc[k][inputKey].push(inputValue);
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, infinite thanks! You're a real lifesaver. I thought I'm gonna spend the rest of my time on this project figuring this one out. This solved my problem *exactly*.